# Which fingerprints could be in request?

Tags: go, web-scraping

i am trying to bypass scrapping protection named "Variti". It uses different fingerprints as I know. I have already tried to change TLS and TCP/IP fingerprint using uTLS lib in go but nothing helped. Are there any other packet fingerprints?

The protection is in mobile app api so doing requests through OkHttp works. But I need a bypass without using emulator/phone

Already tried TLS and TCP/IP fingerprint change

Answer (score 0):

- **Headers** => specify headers
- **TLS** => uTLS lib
- **TCP / IP** => residential proxy rotation (for example from asocks)
- **javascript fingerprinting** (selenium) => use some library like [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles) or undetected-chromedriver (only-Python)
- [okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) supports `HTTP/2`, `uTLS` doesn't tho, maybe that's being detected ?

Disclosure: I am the Author of Selenium-Profiles

Comment: No, that didn't worked. There are no js fingerprint cause its mobile api and there are no webview. Headers are fully correct (cause I used them in okhttp and that worked). I was using my own phone as proxy and checked that tcp fingerprint matched with android. So nothing worked...

Comment: No, request made using http/1.1. Viewed in Charles proxy